# Springboot with Localdatetime and resteasy client

Tags: java-8, resteasy, jackson-modules

I using springboot to return one LocalDateTime and LocalDate parameter, so in my back I put:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

and in application properties :

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false
```

so now my back return this 2 type:

```
entrada": "2017-01-01T22:00:00", // LocalDateTime
"previsao": "2017-01-01",//LocalDate
```

in my front I using:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

and in my class:

```
ResteasyClient client;
    ProtocoloClient protocoloClient;
    public ProtocoloClientImpl() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
        ;
        client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().register(mapper).build();
        ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8181/");
        protocoloClient = target.proxy(ProtocoloClient.class);

    }
```

So when I call my back I got the erro:

javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: br.com.exmart.indicadorRTDPJ.service.rest.vo.ProtocoloVO["entrada"])

I alredy try to put in my

```
public class ProtocoloVO {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime entrada;
```

but got the same error

I alredy try to put

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
private LocalDateTime entrada;
```

Comment: Question ? Why do you have 2 datetime format ? Can't you align with same ?